# how get 24 hour date from DateField in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Normally we can get this("2014-04-24 04:50:10 PM") type of date and time from dateField.I need 24 hour date format like this "2014-04-24 16:50:10" . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dateformatter

```
 <mx:DateFormatter id="dateFormatter" formatString="YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"/>
```

An example is at the very end [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#formatString)